# How can we use sass to to evaluate javascript?

Tags: sass, less

Less.js has an interesting feature where you can reference javascript and evaluate CSS based on this, eg:

```
@color: ~`window.main_color`;

.test {
  background-color: @color;
}
```

Is there something similar for Sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No as Sass is evaluated before sending to client. Less can be send as is and evaluate on client side, and then you can evaluate JS like `window.main_color`. But IMHO it's bad idee because it can provide some WTF when someone display it.

Comment: It's an even worse idea because the compilation is happening on the client and takes time.